# Number with more than 15 digits converts to 0 while writing to CSV file

Tags: java, string, csv, numeric

I have to prepare a string with data and commas. Then write that string to a csv file using `java.util.zip.ZipEntry.`

Now the problem is: it works fine for the number which are less than or equal to 15 in length.

For numeric data more than 15 digits long gets converted to 0.

So I tried by using enclosing numeric data between double quotes for converting numeric data to string to avoid that issue. But that is not working.

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("my.csv");
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zo = new ZipOutputStream(ba);
zo.putNextEntry(ze);
String csv = "123456789012345,12345678901234567890,\"hello\",";

zo.write(csv.getBytes());
zo.closeEntry();
```

can anyone suggest something on this?

Comment: Add your code to your question. That fact that numbers are from 0 to 15 can give you a hint.

Comment: Where is the problem? Is Java sending the wrong number or the program you use to open CSV files interpreting them bad? If is the latter try opening the CSV with notepad and check the number correctness. Also post your code.

Comment: What "number" do you use? A length of 15 maximum doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: How do you viewing your file?

Comment: How could there be a problem with the length of the number? You are not even converting that string to a number in the first place! Maybe you should show the code where you are actually converting that string to a number!

Comment: @tobias_k I tried that but its not working. I  copied the part where I am generating the csv file

Comment: @AleksandrM I am using response object to send this content to browser but I have copied the required content only

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: you are opening the generated csv in MS Excel.

Use a text editor to check the file.

There is a bug report which says: ["Last digits are changed to zeroes when you type long numbers in cells of Excel"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells)